# Next web page after autoshare

Tags: facebook

Im after an `AUTOSHARE button` that shares your website url directly to the clickers facebook page but also takes them to a new page of your website so people cannot proceed  to websites next page unless they share it to facebook,
 *EG: want to find out more about cats? click here.* (posts my website to users facebook page but sends user to "more about cats " page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on
>   your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other
>   actions.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

That means: "share Gating" or "incentivizing" is not allowed. People need to share something only because they really want to, not because they get access to some content or to get rewarded for sharing.

I´ll not get into detail about how it can be done because it´s not allowed anyway, but you would need to authorize a user with `publish_actions` and post to the `/me/feed` endpoint. `publish_actions` needs to get approved by Facebook before any user can use it, but you will never get it approved for stuff like that - again, because it´s not allowed.

Also, the shared message always must be 100% user generated and the user must be aware at any point that a share to Facebook will happen. (Thanx to CBroe for the additional input)

Comment: And it is also not allowed to share when the user only clicks a link saying “click here” – they must be aware at any point that a share to Facebook will happen.

Comment: yeah, forgot to mention that, thanx :)

Comment: Thanks guys, I am sure I have clicked on facebook posts that you must repost to continue, but if it is NOT ALLOWED then I will not do it